# error in Symfony while using salesforce connected app

Tags: symfony, salesforce, hwioauthbundle

In my Symfony2 project i need to `login` with `Salesforce` users so i installed `HwiOAuthBundle` and i created a `connected app` in `Salesforce` to get the customer and secret key, but when i try to `login` in my `Symfony2` application i get this strange error:

```
error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration
```

after consulting many forums i think that i have problem with callback url in Salesforce.

i have also the `facebook` configuration to login with `facebook` users and it works for me but with `SalesForce` it doesn't.

This the configuration of the connected app in `salesforce`:

```
Connected App Name: testApp
Email: my own email
Logo Image URL  : i choosed the default one that salesforce provide
Icon URL    : same as Logo Image URL    
callback url:http://localhost/Annonces/web/app_dev.php/platform/oauth/callback
Selected OAuth Scopes : Full access
```

and the configuration in Symfony:
**config.yml**

```
hwi_oauth:
  firewall_name: main
  http_client:
      verify_peer: false     
  resource_owners:
    facebook:
      type: facebook
      client_id: "%oauth.facebook.id%"
      client_secret: "%oauth.facebook.secret%"
      scope: "email"
    salesforce:
        type: salesforce
        client_id: "%oauth.salesforce.id%"
        client_secret: "%oauth.salesforce.secret%"
```

**security.yml**

```
security:

    acl:
        connection: default

    encoders:
        OC\UserBundle\Entity\User: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER:        ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

    providers:        
        mine:
            id: ib_user.oauth_user_provider

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false                         

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: true

            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    facebook: "/login/check-facebook"
                    salesforce: "/login/check-salesforce"
                login_path: /login
                failure_path: /login
                default_target_path: /platform
                oauth_user_provider: 
                    service: ib_user.oauth_user_provider


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

**routing.yml**

```
oc_platform:
    resource: "@OCPlatformBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /platform     

user_logout:
     resource: "@OCUserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"  
     prefix:   /logout 

hwi_oauth_login:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix:   /login

hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect

facebook_login: 
    pattern: /login/check-facebook   

salesforce_login: 
    pattern: /login/check-salesforce
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have finally find a solution: in the `connected app` in `salesforce` i set the `callback url` parameter to this : 
 http://localhost/Annonces/web/app_dev.php/login/check-salesforce

so i just added:**/login/check-salesforce**  and it works.